# SQLITE table join error ambiguous column name - tables sharing a column name

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I have a problem in inserting values of one table into another.

Building a test.db:

```
CREATE TABLE CORE_information
(Department REAL,
PERSON TEXT);

CREATE TABLE SKILLS_detailed
(Department REAL,
PERSON TEXT,
SKILLS TEXT,
Line_Manager TEXT);

CREATE TABLE ALL_HR_skills 
(Department REAL,
PERSON TEXT,
SKILLS TEXT);

INSERT INTO Core_information (Department, Person) VALUES (1, 'George');
INSERT INTO Core_information (Department, Person) VALUES (1, 'Alan');
INSERT INTO Core_information (Department, Person) VALUES (2, 'Maria');
INSERT INTO Core_information (Department, Person) VALUES (2, 'Andrea');    

INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'George', 'Skill 1', 'A' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'George', 'Skill 1', 'B' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'Alan', 'Skill 1', 'A' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'Alan', 'Skill 1', 'B' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (2, 'Maria', 'Skill 1', 'A' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (2, 'Maria', 'Skill 1', 'B' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (2, 'Maria', 'Skill 1', 'C' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'Andrea', 'Skill 1', 'A' );
INSERT INTO SKILLS_detailed (Department, Person, Skills, Line_Manager) VALUES (1, 'Andrea', 'Skill 1', 'B' );


INSERT into ALL_HR_skills (Department, Person)
SELECT Department, Person 
FROM Core_information;
```

I need to add to the table ALL_HR_Skills the first SKILL of the table SKILLS_detailed .
The code that gives me the error is this one:

```
INSERT INTO ALL_HR_skills(SKILLS)
SELECT SKILLS
FROM SKILLS_detailed
INNER JOIN ALL_HR_SKILLS
ON DEPARTMENT.ALL_HR_SKILLS = DEPARTMENT.SKILLS_DETAILED
AND PERSON.ALL_HR_SKILLS = PERSON.SKILLS_DETAILED;

Error: ambiguous column name: SKILLS
```

Is the problem that the SKILLS_detailed and ALL_HR_skills tables share a column name?
How do I make the INSERT SELECT and FROM statements more specific on column and table?

Comment: `select SKILLS_detailed.SKILLS ...`

Comment: a) I see that for SELECT you put the table name first: SELECT table_name.column_name, whereas in the JOIN it's the opposite, is this random or an actual coding suggestion?

Comment: b) when I apply 'SELECT SKILLS_detailed.SKILLS ...' I get a new error: Error: no such column: Department.ALL_HR_SKILLS

Comment: Because it should be `ALL_HR_SKILLS.Department` and not `Department.ALL_HR_SKILLS`

Comment: Thank you, now it actually joins, however not on the right rows. It shifts the inserted SKILLS values in the rows after the Department and Person which are empty    `INSERT into ALL_HR_SKILLS(SKILLS)    SELECT SKILLS_detailed.SKILLS    FROM SKILLS_detailed    INNER JOIN ALL_HR_SKILLS     ON ALL_HR_SKILLS.Department = SKILLS_detailed.Department    AND ALL_HR_SKILLS.Person = SKILLS_detailed.Person;`